# Same result with methods of type void and int, which to use?

Tags: java

I have the following main class:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Counter counter1;
        Counter counter2;
        counter1 = new Counter();
        counter2 = new Counter();

        counter1.increment();
        counter2.increment();
        counter2.increment();

        System.out.println(counter1.getValue());
        System.out.println(counter2.getValue());
    }
}
```

And the class `Counter`:

```
public class Counter {

    private int count;

    public Counter() {
       count = 0;
    }

    public void increment() {
        count++;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

I got the result (from counter1 and counter2, respectively):

```
1   
2
```

But if I instead change the method `increment`  to type `int`, i.e.

```
public class Counter {

    private int count;

    public Counter() {
        count = 0;
    }

    public int increment() {
        return count++;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

I got the same result:

```
1   
2
```

I know `void` doesn't return any value, however, is there any purpose of using `void` over `int` (or vice versa) in this example?

Comment: This is dangerous code: `public int increment() {
        return count++;
    }` as you're returning count *before* it has been incremented, and this will likely cause confusion. Better to `return ++count;` if you want to do this

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent the wheel respectively [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write code to do two things:

- solve some problem (like implementing a counter and providing access to the internal state of that counter)
- communicate your intentions to human readers

You can decide to use void to indicate that calling *increment()* is not meant to give you any insights into the current counter count. You could use the int return type to tell your readers that the method also provides that information. But in the second case you might also slightly change the method name, to "incrementAndGet()" for example.

When you check out classes like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html you will find that pattern "do something and return the new state" quite often.

And yes, one could see it as a violation of srp to return a value from result, but as my example shows, sometimes it is helpful or actually mandatory to deviate slightly...

Comment: You are very welcome. Positive feedback from you always feels like accolade :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using "int" here because you are getting the value of count with another method. If you wouldn't have the "getValue" method you would need to use "int" to get the value.
But because you have the "getValue" method you should not use "int" because is it a violation of the "single responsibility principle".

Comment: Not necessarily. It might be useful for to get the accumulated value from the operation itself, instead of forcing the user to call get afterwards.

Comment: I've learnt to to always use getter and setter methods to manipulate a value from another class. I agree with you that you can use the return type `int` to get the new value immediately back, but I think that should then be a private method and only be used inside the same class

Comment: The better lesson is: don't use neither getters nor setters. The internal state should not be so easily available (to a certain degree). Getters can lead to violation of "tell don't ask" and setters are the first step into the dark abyss anyway :-)